# DELETE not found; rails + angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

**CODE:**

Rails controller:

```
def destroy
  respond_with Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
end
```

Angular factory:

```
.factory('posts', [
  '$http',
  function($http) {
    var o = {
      posts: []
    };
    o.destroy = function(post) {
      return $http.delete('posts.json', post).success(function(data) {
        o.posts.splice(o.posts.indexOf(data), 1);
      });
    };
    return o;
  }
]);
```

Part of a main module:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates', 'Devise'])
.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

   $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts) {
          return posts.getAll();
        }]
      }
    })
  }
 ]);
```

mainCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
function($scope, posts) {
  $scope.posts = posts.posts;
  ...
  $scope.destroy = function(post) {
    posts.destroy(post);
  };
}
]);
```

**PROBLEM:**
When trying to click on delete button `ng-click="destroy(post)"`  - it doesn't work and gives me the error:

> DELETE http://localhost:3000/posts.json 404 (Not Found)

The interesting part is when I change my `$http.delete` to `$http.post` - it works, but on refresh I have 2 same posts(obviously).
I am a newbie in both angular and rails, so I would really appreciate your help.

**Rake routes:**
[image: Rake routes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got this.
The problem was in this row: `return $http.delete('posts.json', post)`. Need to change this to
`return $http.delete('/posts/' + post.id + '.json')`, as `rake routes` says it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `resources :posts` in your rails routes file.

Comment: I used to have `resources :posts, only: [:show, :create, :index]` and I've removed this. Now it looks like you said. Maybe it needs some refresh?

Comment: What does rake routes produce?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Thanks for you help, got the solution :)